# Unable to fetch specific column that from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, fetch

I have created a an entity called `Statutory` with four columns namely `name`,`complianceName`,`statMappingName`,`country`

i want a get all `complianceName` names that matches a specific `statMappingName`. Following is my code

```
 NSString *nameToGet = self.statNameArray[indexPath.row] ;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"complianceName = %@", nameToGet];
        [fetch setPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"n %@",predicate);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    if(results) {
        NSLog(@"Entities with that name: %@", results);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
```

But it is not providing the compliance name specific to that `statMappingName`. How can I be able to get all `complianceName` that has a specific  `statMappingName`?

Comment: what error is coming?

Comment: its returning an empty array

Comment: i want to fetch all `complianceName` from a row that contains `statMappingName`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch  specific column from `core data`

You can use the below method:-

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityname inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setFetchLimit:1];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(complianceName LIKE %@)",nametoGet]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *tempDataArr = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Note:-

*entityname: Your entity name

*self.managedObjectContext : Your managedobjectcontext

To Get All compliance Name use the below method

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entityName]; 
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]; 
NSMutableArray *tempDataArr =[NSMutableArray new]; 
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY complianceName LIKE %@)",nametoGet]]; 
tempDataArr = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: i want to fetch all `complianceName` from a row that contains `statMappingName`

Comment: NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entityName];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSMutableArray *tempDataArr =[NSMutableArray new];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY complianceName LIKE %@)",nametoGet]];
            tempDataArr = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

Comment: it returns nothing bro

Comment: set your entity name and other required parameters

Comment: For example lets say that there are three attributes like firstname,middlename,lastname. I want to fetch all firstname that matches a specific lastname ....

Comment: likewise i want to fetch all complianceName that matches the specific statMappingName

Comment: [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY complianceName LIKE %@)",nametoGet]];

Comment: it returns empty value

Comment: or i wanna  i fetch an entire row that contains a specific statmappingName. From that row, I can get the complianceName later.

Comment: In core data you need to iterate particular attribute data from the array of entities

Comment: can you please eloborate?

Comment: NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@""];

fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"complianceName", nil]];

NSError *error      = nil;
NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                               error:&error];

NSMutableArray * complianceNames = [NSMutableArray array];

for(id currentRecord in results)
{
    [complianceNames addObject:[currentRecord objectForKey:@"complianceName"]];
}

Comment: you try with this ,its not exactly what u want ,do some experiments

Comment: yeah bro that works but i want only the complianceName that has got specific statMappingName..How can i sort it out?

Comment: use predicate with results array

Comment: Sure
        You can use predicate with the results array.You just check predicate usage with nsarray that will help you to sort out this

Comment: Thank you bro for your answers. I got it done with this code `NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ApproveStatutoryMappings"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"statutortMappingName == %@", _statNameArray[indexPath.row]];
    
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObjectContext * info in results){
        NSLog(@" %@",[info valueForKey:@"complianceName"]);
    }` Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
NSString *firstName = statMappingName;
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == %@", firstName]];
```

Comment: i want the compliance name corresponding to the stat mapping name.

Comment: For example lets say that there are three attributes like `firstname`,`middlename`,`lastname`. I want to fetch all firstname that matches a specific lastname

Comment: Thank you bro for your answers. I got it done with this code `NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ApproveStatutoryMappings"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"statutortMappingName == %@", _statNameArray[indexPath.row]];
    
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObjectContext * info in results){
        NSLog(@" %@",[info valueForKey:@"complianceName"]);
    }` Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try these code for contains statMappingName

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"complianceName contains[c] %@", statMappingName];
```

Comment: Lets say that there are three attributes like firstname,middlename,lastname. I want to fetch all firstname that matches a specific lastname .... likewise i want to fetch all complianceName that matches the specific statMappingName...

Comment: you want to match then use  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"complianceName = %@", statMappingName];

Comment: okay...how can i fetch an entire row that contains a specific statmappingName....

Comment: if i can fetch the entire row that has a specific statMappingName then I will be able to get the complianceName from that specific  row

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I got it done with this code `NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ApproveStatutoryMappings"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"statutortMappingName == %@", _statNameArray[indexPath.row]];
    
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObjectContext * info in results){
        NSLog(@" %@",[info valueForKey:@"complianceName"]);
    }` Thanks again